# How to use standard Linux tools to fix a deadlocked script?

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, buffer, buffer-overflow

I have a script in Python3 and if I use `subprocess.Popen.wait()` I have problem — my script iterates some Linux command many times and it looks to me like my app is not responding. When I use `subprocess.Popen.communicate()` my application correctly completes its work in a second.
**What is the right way to solve this problem using Linux?**

**I think the solution must be somewhere in manipulating with buffer's variable**, but I searched through the entire Internet and could not find anything suitable. May be I don't know enough structure and operation of Linux as a whole.

My question can be reformulated as follows: **What's happened exactly when I use .wait() method? And that leads to failure of it? What is the cause of the so long waiting?** When I aborting running task I see the next log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 6, in <module>
    proc.wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1658, in wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py", line 1608, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

My files looks approximately like the next things:
script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-

import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen(['./1.py', '1000000'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.wait()
out = proc.stdout.read()
# out = proc.communicate()[0]
print(len(out))
```

1.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*-coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

x = sys.argv[-1]

# print(x, type(x))
for i in range(int(x)):
  print(i)
```

UPD: As we understand, the problem is a buffer overflow. It turns out the last version of question is, **how to use the Linux possibility to expand buffer or redirect buffer to a file before running the script?**

UPD2: I also tried run the script as: $ **python3 -u ./script.py**, but, unfortunally, unbufferring doesn't work as I would like and script is hangs.

Comment: could you please include the code you tried?

Comment: You have not understood the problem fully. You need to sit down & think thru this more. There is a reason why the process is not completing. May be you can do some logging in the child process.

Comment: Can you give us the `Popen` call you use? Does it do anything with stdout and stderr?

Comment: @JohnSmith - edit your question with that stuff so its more readable!

Comment: @tdelaney thanks. I'm a first time use this website in quiestion mode!

Comment: @kmario23 I added the code!

Comment: I think my answer fixes your problem. Just use `communicate`. If it works for you, accept the answer so others know its done. If not, let me know what doesn't work.

Comment: @tdelaney My question is about how to solve this trouble via using Linux tools?

Comment: You can't fix this without changing the code in some way.

Comment: I don't understand why you're not using communicate when you know it works properly. You say you want to "solve this problem using Linux" but I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @Blckknght.. It's interesting question. I think something is going wrong.  **I think the solution must be somewhere in manipulating with buffer's variable**, but I searched through the entire Internet and could not find anything suitable. May be I don't know enough structure and operation of Linux as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script is sending output to its `stdout` or `stderr` pipes. The operating system will buffer some data then block the process forever when the pipe fills. Suppose I have a long winded command like

longwinded.py:

```
for i in range(100000):
    print('a'*1000)
```

The following hangs because the stdout pipe fills

```
import sys
import subprocess as subp
p = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'longwinded.py'], stdout=subp.PIPE,
    stderr=subp.PIPE)
p.wait()
```

The next one doesn't hang because `communicate` reads the stdout and stderr pipes into memory

```
p = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'longwinded.py'], stdout=subp.PIPE,
    stderr=subp.PIPE)
p.communicate()
```

If you don't care what stdout and err are, you can redirect them to the null device

```
p = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'longwinded.py'], 
    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'), 
    stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
p.wait()
```

or save them to a file

```
p = subp.Popen([sys.executable, 'longwinded.py'], 
    stdout=open('mystdout', 'w'), 
    stderr=open('mystderr', 'w'))
p.wait()
```

Comment: If I understood your answer correctly, main idea is to allow the buffer to redirect to file. In my case I need in the end of my script to reads stdout. If I can do it (redirect buffer to the file by using OS tools), used pipes cannot be filled and this process don't be blocked!

Comment: But is it possible to use Linux tools?.. I was read about **tee** command, but using of this one have the next mode: **./script.py | tee output.file**. But it means that buffer redirection happend after finishing of script. But I need to redirect buffer before starting the script.

Comment: If you want to 'redirect buffer before starting the script' (which is an inaccurate statement, since you are not 'redirecting', but merely 'directing', and its not the 'buffer' but the 'output') just do it.  Instead of passing `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` to subprocess.POPEN`, direct stdout to where you want it.

Comment: @JohnSmith The problem is that your _script.py_ hangs because it does a wait then a read. Its a classic deadlock - the wait can't return until the read is done. No external program can fix that. _script.py_ has a bug and _script.py_ must be changed. `tee` will wait for data from script.py that will never come because script.py hung

Comment: @tdelaney My understanding of this case is the next: hung is happened because 1 million of itteration inside the pipe clog the one's (pipe's)  buffer and the .wait() can't regain control. It's means if size of buffer for pipe would be extended (or written on the disk), then the buffer is not full and everything goes correctly. In another words - a pipe is a weakspot.. or I do not properly, not fully understand Pipe and pipe's buffer. its really strange, because **seq 1000000** command in Linux is performed for a few seconds, but the same code in the Python's pipe hung up the console.

Comment: You are right, the problem is that the pipe fills. The problem is that the pipe is created when the process is forked by script.py and other tools can't get in there and redirect. It has to be script.py itself. I assume you don't have control over script.py or you'd fix this easy bug. If the maintainers don't handle bug reports then you'll have to abandon it completely.

Comment: Maybe it's a limits of Python env and using some variables during start Py's script can be solve the trouble?

Comment: But as I wrote above: I also tried run the script as: $ python3 -u ./script.py, but, unfortunally, unbufferring doesn't work as I would like and script is hungs. In this situation, I need think about your assumptions/understandings... In any case - very thank you, for your @tdelaney participation and help!